# using brm function but encounter "Compiling the C++ model No C++ compiler found ..."

Tags: c++, r

I am using brm function but encounter the following problem. So I followed the instruction to install Rtools. But it returns the same error message ... Does anyone have the experience in solving this problem?

Compiling the C++ model
No C++ compiler found, so the following will probably not work.

See https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/Installing-RStan-on-Windows#toolchain

Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! Warning message:

In system(cmd) : 'make' not found

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In system2(file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "bin", Sys.getenv("R_ARCH_BIN"),
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin//R" CMD config CXX' had status 1

2: In system(cmd, intern = !verbose) :
  running command 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.1/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB file4a701b336a9f.cpp 2> file4a701b336a9f.cpp.err.txt' had status 1

Comment: have you restarted R since you installed Rtools?

Comment: With windows it sometimes helps to reboot the computer.